# Executing python code with input arguments from VSCode terminal

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a file named `test.py` open in VSCode.

Inside the file, I have the following function:

```py
def test(array):
   print('Test Function Invoked')
   print(array)
```

Question is how do I invoke the function test and pass an input argument say `[4,2,1,3]` from VSCode Terminal ?

Comment: If you're trying to run tests, I suggest making sure you have the approvd python extension installed, configure your test framework, and you can then run the tests individually  - you'll get a `run test` link above each one.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, just ask the user to input the array before calling the function.

Here is the solution

```
array = input('enter an array: ') #<-- this will ask user to enter an array
def test(array):
   print('Test Function Invoked')
   print(array)
```

Now execute in VS terminal

> enter an array: [1,2,34]

Now pass this array to the function in the vs terminal

```
test(array)
```

And the output will be this

> Test Function Invoked
>
> [1,2,34]

For parsing the array from command line. Use the below code-

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-a", "--array", required=True,
                help="enter a valid array")
args = ap.parse_args()

def test(array = args.array):
    print('array added successfully')
    print(array)

test()
```

To execute the code from the command line. Run this command.

```
run try.py -a [5,6,7]
```

### Output

> array added successfully
>
> [5,6,7]

Comment: My question is about invoking this script from command line / terminal ..Using  "input" is not what I am looking for.